# How to access MySQL database from deployed JSP web app in Apache Tomcat

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat

I just deployed my first JSP web application on Tomcat server and I'm using MySQL database. However, I keep getting errors when I try to query data from MySQL. Any ideas? and the error I,m seeing is as shown below:

```
   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
   sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem by including the missing MySQL java connector jar file to the tomcat "lib" folder.

Thanks guys!